# Как сверстать несколько элементов с общим фоном?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Надо сверстать два шестиугольника с общим фоном как тут на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что (и как) вы пробовали сделать ?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Я закрываю этот вопрос с той же формулировкой, что предоставил александр баракин: мы хотим переломить ситуацию с вопросами-картинками, поэтому пусть побудет закрытым, пока не будет приведён в порядок. Если найдутся добровольцы, которые готовы привести в порядок -- готов переоткрыть и объявить конкурс.

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто вырезать оба шестиугольника вместе как уже у вас есть на картинке, при этом всё что за бортом шестиугольников сделать альфа каналом. То есть оба шестиугольника будут одной картинкой.

Comment: Дмитрий, [вопросы-картинки -- достаточно непростая тема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5298/213987), но раз уж вы взялись за ответ, то не хотите ли привести в порядок вопрос? Нужно-то всего ничего: придумать внятный заголовок, чтобы можно было искать по подобным вопросом. Кроме того, хотелось бы более подробного решения в общем случае (и с кодом, да). Согласен, дело непростое, могу пообещать дополнительные баллы репутации путём открытия конкурса.

Comment: @AK Как вам вариант темы: "Как сверстать два многоугольника с общим фоном"? На самом деле мне этот вопрос не нравится тем что он пересекается с темой сделать несколько дырок и назад положить фон... А это совсем другой случай чем я предложил...

Comment: @AK можно просто новый вопрос придумать под более общюю тему, не думаю что стоит этот вопрос апгрейдить. Могу сам вопрос написать... Как-то было желание сделать кнопки-прямоугольники с общим фоном, кстати так и не сделал в результате, просто сделал более простой дизайн.

Comment: @AK Сделал апгрейд названия: Как сверстать несколько эллементов с общим фоном.

Comment: Можно и новый вопрос, не обязательно спасать этот -- его можно потом переоткрыть и придубликатить. Я лично вижу задачу, когда фон -- картинка, которая находится на заднем плане и полностью перекрыта белым фоном. И вопрос -- как прорубать дырки в этом белом фоне, открывая части картинки.

Comment: @AK Сделал новый вопрос, хотя он и не идентичен этому https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760232/Как-сверстать-несколько-кнопок-с-общим-фоном

Comment: Общего много и это хорошо. Различие на то, что дырки всегда прямоугольные (а можно ли добавить несколько разных дырок -- кругом, шестиугольником?). Плюс, здесь есть термин "кнопка" -- я с трудом представляю потребность в отдельной шестиугольной кнопке, поэтому это тоже отступление от вопроса. PS  Приписал пояснение, чтобы не минусовали не прочитавши.

Comment: @AK да, это несколько другой вопрос, но пусть пока будет именно так, так как такой вопрос у меня реально был. То что дырки прямоугольные это более конкретизирует вопрос, но зато он реальный, и решения могут быть специфические с учётом что дырки могут задавать просто как блок CSS с border-radius. Хотя я пока не могу сказать можно ли это использовать или нет... тут надо уже думать и отвечать.

Comment: @AK попозже можно будет задать вопрос с произвольными дырами.

Comment: Ок, начнём с малого.