# Как сверстать прямоугольные блоки с общим фоном

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, изображения

У меня есть вертикальная панель блоков / кнопок.

Я хочу сделать так что бы у них был общий фон, как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходная картинка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: просьба к читающим вопрос: перед тем, как бросаться минусовать вопрос ознакомиться с [темой на мете про вопросы-картинки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5298/213987) и поглядеть  [изначальный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759912/213987), с которого началась эта тема. Это НЕ учебный вопрос, это попытка написать эталонную закрывашку

Comment: а при скролле по вертикали и горизонтали фон должен с кнопками двигаться или на месте быть? потому что может зависеть решение... если все же сохранять положение на них свое - то скорее всего без js никак (за исключением варианта подгонки изображения по position)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский оба варианта, или любой из них будет интересен. Что бы было без JavaScript не обязательно, принимаются все решения.

Comment: Если не прокручивая страницу, `background-attachment: fixed;` для кнопок, наверное, подойдет...

Answer (score 7):

Тут банально используется **[background-attachment: fixed](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-attachment)** на картинках.

```css
.image-fixed {
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO1xf.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 70%;
    background-position: -8px 2px;
    border-radius: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
}

#common {
  background: blue;  
}
```

```html
<div id="common">
  <div class="image-fixed">text</div>
  <div class="image-fixed">text</div>
  <div class="image-fixed">text</div>
  content content content content  <br/>
  content content content content  <br/>
  content content content content  <br/>
  content content content content  <br/>
  content content content content  <br/>
  content content content content  <br/>
  content content content content  <br/>
  content content content content  <br/>
  content content content content  <br/>
</div>
```

Недостаток тут очевиден - при скролле картинка остается на месте. Какие хаки применить, причем без использования *Javascript*, чтобы блок дивов двигался вместе с картинкой - я пока не знаю

Comment: Кстати, что интересно, что при расположении вертикального меню fixed работать будет как надо, а это достаточно частая ситуация. И самое интересное что в моей задачи как раз такой случай ))

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин ну да, отдельным блоком - вполне сработает. Но если рассматривать как универсальщину - то увы

Answer (score 3):

```css
.box {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO1xf.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn::after {
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  content: '';
  bottom: -11px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="" class="btn">Кнопка</a>
    <a href="" class="btn">Кнопка</a>
    <a href="" class="btn">Кнопка</a>
    <a href="" class="btn">Кнопка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот но на мой взгляд костыли

Comment: список костылей стоит добавить в ответ

Comment: Прикольно будет если окажется, что задник может быть не монотонный :)

Comment: Интересное решение, правда скруглённых углов тут не сделать как я понимаю.